# useParams doesn't work properly return empty object

Tags: typescript, react-hooks, react-router-dom

The `useParams` hook returns undefined. I don't understand what the problem is.

App.tsx

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <div className="App">
    <Navigation />
    <Routes>
      <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/work/:id" element={<Work />} />
    </Routes>
    <Footer />
  </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Navigation.tsx

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
const Navigation = () => {
  const {id} = useParams();
  
  console.log(id); // Here show undefined

  return (
    <nav>
      <div className={style.logo}>
        <img src={Logo} alt="logo" />
      </div>
    </nav>
  )
}

export default Navigation
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Navigation` component should be moved *into* the `Routes` component that is managing the routes and route matching. In other words, it is the `Routes` component that knows what routes it has and what the route path params are.

Example:

```
import { Routes, Route, Outlet, useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const Navigation = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();

  console.log("Navigation", { id });

  return (
    <nav>
      <div className={style.logo}>
        <img src={Logo} alt="logo"/>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
};
```

```
<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route element={<NavLayout />}>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/work/:id" element={<Work />} />
    </Route>
  </Routes>
  <Footer />
</Router>
```

### Demo

[image: Edit useparams-doesnt-work-properly-return-empty-object]